# fusionchart in IE and Mozilla

Tags: internet-explorer, mozilla, fusioncharts

I get an error like 'htmlfile: Unknown runtime error' while trying to show fusion chart on a pop-up window in IE 8. But it works fine in Mozilla 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re getting an “unknown runtime error” in internet explorer while using the javascript method object.innerHTML=”…some html”, here is a hint to put you on the right track: you’re probabily trying to put a block-level element inside an inline element.

Please read http://www.gljakal.com/blog/2006/02/19/unknown-runtime-error-in-internet-explorer/

I am not sure of the code used by you. Please share your code here.